# Can UserScripts in the "scripts" tab be sorted in a similar manner as applications are in the "apps" tab?

Tags: feature-request

If you bring up the [Stack Apps home page](http://stackapps.com) (the `apps` tab), you will notice that the items are sorted according to their score and recent activity.

Can we please sort the UserScripts (the `scripts` tab) the same way?